# Is there a good way in C++11 to store references to other objects as a members?

Tags: c++, oop, c++11, design-patterns, ownership

Good day, everybody!

Here is where I stuck:
I have three concrete classes: `Computer`, `Peripheral` and `Person`.
`Computer` and `Peripheral` are both extend class `Device`.

`Device` has a private member `Device.owner`: `Person`, which should store some kind of a reference to an owner of the device, and a public function `Device.getOwner()`: `Person`.

On the other hand, any `Person` has its own private members `Person.peripherals` and `Person.computers` and public functions `Person.get()` ...  etc.

**Is there are any design patterns to build these connections between classes?**

**Without transferring direct ownership! (the `Computer` has no rights to kill instance of `Person` etc. that is why I beware of using pointers)**

**BUT** if some instances of `Computer` will change its owner so it must be disappeared from the list of computers of the previous owner and appeared in the list of the new owner. Same thing with `Peripheral`.

Please, ask any questions if you have some. Probably, my explanation of the situation is poor. Sorry for lang mistakes.

Comment: Maybe you should consider using `weak_ptr`s?

Answer (score 1):

You can use std::unique_ptr to ensure that a single reference exists to that object. To change the ownership use std::move.

```
std::unique_ptr<Device> devicePtr(new Device());
std::unique_ptr<Device> devicePtr2(std::move(devicePtr));
```

Each Person would have it's unique pointer(s).